# ReactNative make image to fade in with background

Tags: react-native

I am trying to achieve Image on background to fade in with background color. Basically I have image on background for half screen but bottom border is kind of sharp I want to make image transition to background smooth. Any suggestions? Something like this:
[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMgyn.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I need to put linear gradient on top of image from transparent to bottom color

```
  <Image
    style={styles.absolute}
    source={{ uri: drink.imageUrl }}
    blurRadius={20}
  />
  <LinearGradient
    colors={['transparent', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)']}
    style={styles.absolute}
  />
```